# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects_Php\pagina_busqueda.php on line 34

Tags: php, html5

Buenos, esperando gentilmente su ayuda, tengo ese error, ya me tiene dando dolor de cabeza, no tengo idea de como solucionarlo, aquí va el código.

Pagina Resultados

```
$db_host = 'localhost';         
$db_nombre = 'registro';        
$db_usuario = 'sergio_roger';
$db_pass = 'sergio_roger';  
$buscar = $_GET['buscar']; $endl = '<br/>'; 

$conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_pass, $db_nombre);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    echo 'Error al conectar a la base de datos ', $endl;
    exit();
}

mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die ('No se encuentra la base de datos');

mysqli_set_charset($conexion, 'utf8');

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE nombre = $buscar";

$resultado =  mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

echo '<h2>Datos de la tabla producto </h2>';

while(($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC))){ //Linea de error

    echo '<table> <tr><td>';
    echo $fila['codigo'], '</td><td>' ;
    echo $fila['seccion'], '</td><td>';
    echo $fila['nombre'], '</td><td>';
    echo $fila['precio'], '</td><td>';
    echo $fila['origen'], '</td><td></tr></table>';
}

mysqli_close($conexion);

unset($endl);
```

?>

Comment: Podrías explicar un poco el código ¿que es lo que intentas hacer? ¿Que resultados esperas? ¿Cual es el detalle del error que te arroja? Si tenes dudas te sugiero que leas Cómo preguntar y como hacer un Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando te salé un error en esa línea significa que el verdadero error está en tu consulta ya que no está trayendo ningún dato válido, intenta agregar `$buscar` entre comillas simples así:

```
"SELECT * FROM producto WHERE nombre = '$buscar'";
```

Si esto no te funciona revisa muy bien que el nombre de la tabla y de la comuna estén copiados exactamente igual.

Espero que te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Hey.. gracias.., por la ayuda, ese detalle solucionó el error, pues la consulta está bien realizada !! Muchas gracias..